# Excluding a table from a Oracle role

Tags: oracle, roles

I have a role for human users through which they get access to all tables in main schema of oracle DB for my application.
I want to create another role where i exclude few tables and keep access to remaining tables.
My preference would be to create a new role and grant it access to the existing role and then i need to find a way to exclude the access to selected tables.
Is this possible or if there there is any other way to achieve this without granting access to each table in new role separately.

Comment: There is no "deny" action in Oracle privilege model, i.e. you cannot explicitly exclude anything. Create a role which grant access only to the tables you like to have.

Comment: Just flip your order of creation.  Create the more limited role, then the more unlimited role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GRANT` a permission and once granted you can `REVOKE` that permission but there is no option for a user to have one role that `GRANT`s a permission and another role that overrides it and `DENY`s the permission as that functionality simply does not exist.

If you want user `A` to have permissions `X, Y, Z` and user `B` to have permissions `X, Y` but not `Z` then you can create two roles, one to grant the permissions `X, Y` and give that to both users and a second role to grant the permission `Z` and only give that to user `A`.